# How to correctly clone a Github repo branch using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to clone a Github repo.

```
Function CloneRepo{
    $solnFolder = -join($outputDir,"\", $newSolutionName)
    git clone -b master "https://github.com/sukesh-y/Stratum.git" $solnFolder
}

$newSolutionName = "MyCompany"
$outputDir = "D:\Test"
CloneRepo
```

This does clone the repo but there is an error in console.
When I execute the script, it throws the error. After many seconds, it shows the `Uploading files` progress.

[image]

[image]

I'm running Windows PowerShell ISE with Admin privileges.
What is this error and how can I avoid it.

Comment: You are getting a Remote Exception. You are trying to write to the remote folder which needs an Admin.  Start PS by right click PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Also you would need to replace the colon in the path with a dollar sign : "D$\Test"

Comment: @jdweng Sorry forgot to mention, but it is with admin privileges. The $ did not work

Comment: Any idea why you are getting the RemoteException?

Comment: @jdweng, neither remoting nor network shares are involved here. That the word `RemoteException` shows up in the error message - which isn't a true error message - is an unfortunate fact of life when using the PowerShell ISE, which is best avoided these days.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

- The **obsolescent PowerShell ISE** is **ill-suited for running *external programs* such as `git`: it inappropriately surfaces *stderr* output *as PowerShell errors* and lacks proper terminal support in general**.

  - Fortunately, these problems do *not* exist in regular console windows, Windows Terminal, or in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal.
  - However, even there stderr lines surface and print as PowerShell errors in the output from *[remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote) calls*, and you can use the techniques below to prevent that. The unexpected as-error *formatting* is less problematic when calling from [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), because only the stderr line *text* prints in red, whereas in *Windows PowerShell* you get the same "noisy", multi-line display for the first stderr line as in the ISE. Also, the `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` caveat discussed below applies to remoting too.
- While you can situationally - suboptimally - work around the problem (see below), you're better off migrating to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

---

Your screenshot implies that you're using the PowerShell *ISE*.

- The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md). The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Among the other reasons not to use it is the case at hand:

- The ISE inappropriately surfaces *stderr* output from external programs *as if they were PowerShell errors*, which is undesired and confusing

  - The fact that the spurious errors surface as `RemoteException` adds to the confusion.
  - More importantly, if [`$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) is in effect, stderr output will *inappropriately abort* your script: you can *not* infer failure of an external-program call from the presence of stderr output; only the *exit code* matters, which must be checked via [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).
- Since external programs only have *two* output streams at their disposal - stdout and stderr - stderr is used for anything that is *not data*, which isn't necessarily just actual *error* messages, but often *status* information.

  - In the case at hand, `git` uses stderr to provide status information in the form of an iteratively updated progress display meant to update *in place*.
  - Because the ISE lacks proper terminal support, each progress update ends up *on a separate line*.
- If migrating to Visual Studio Code is not an option, you have three options to deal with the problem, all of them suboptimal:

  - You can *ignore* the problem, and put up with the visual disruption.
  - You can *silence* stderr output with `2>$null` - which means you'll lose not only the status information, but potentially error messages too:

    ```
    # Suppress all stderr output
    git ... 2>$null
    ```
  - You can merge stderr into PowerShell's success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) with `2>&1`, and convert the `ErrorRecord` instances that represent the stderr output to strings with `% ToString` (`%` is a built-in alias of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet):

    ```
    # Merge stderr output into the success output stream and stringify.
    # Note: If you *capture* the results, you'll get the stdout and
    #       stderr *combined*.
    git ... 2>&1 | % ToString
    ```
- None of these workarounds work well in your particular case (progress display), because the information doesn't print until *after* the command has finished (except that with the first option the *first*, verbose error message prints *right away*).

Comment: Go vscode. https://code.visualstudio.com/download